# Why can´t we answer this question

Tags: bug, status-completed

Why am I not able to give an answer to this question:

[I’m 18 years old and want to finance a £30,000 car](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/117885/i-m-18-years-old-and-want-to-finance-a-%c2%a330-000-car)

Presumable, because it already has a lot of answers?
*Edit: apparently a bug?*

I know there are a lot of answers already, and I only answer those if I think I have an answer that brings something new to the table. I thought the purpose of this site was to get the best answers possible. If a popular question that attracts a lot of answers is closed for new answers quickly, we no longer get the best answers, but the quickest answers - which are not always the ones which got the most though and content put into them.

This is how it looks like:
[image]

I could post when I reloaded the page and then posted quickly. The orange message only seems to appear after some time in the editor. Does not seem to be affected by the "protected" status.

Comment: Are you sure you can't answer it? It's only protected for low-rep users, you're well over the threshold.

Comment: Yep. Once I try to answer a orange bar at the top appears with the letters "This question has been locked - no more answers will be accepted." and the "Post Answer" button is inactive. Not before some thought and some writing was done by me already, of course.

Comment: I just posted an answer? 
 https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/117885/i-m-18-years-old-and-want-to-finance-a-%c2%a330-000-car/117988#117988

Comment: @quid I unprotected it temporarily on the advice of SE staff - there seems to be a bug, perhaps in the interaction between comment lock and protection. I've just protected it again now Daniel has posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some help from StackExchange staff, it looks like you hit some variant of this bug:
[Receiving incorrect WebSocket message "this post is locked - no more edits are allowed" when editing a post on which comments are disabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340287/receiving-incorrect-websocket-message-this-post-is-locked-no-more-edits-are-a)

The post was deliberately:

- Comment locked - as the question had got lots of comments that were basically answers or otherwise not very useful
- Protected - roughly for the reasons discussed [here](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2545/why-was-this-hot-network-question-protected)

But you have plenty of reputation and were trying to answer not comment, so you were not an intended target of those restrictions.

I've now removed the comment lock to stop this affecting anyone else. But please try to keep the comments down :-)